# In Tomcat, how do I redirect the URL from a former WAR file to another WAR file?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I have a Tomcat server where I have two war files deployed. The apps are REST services; let's call them **dummy.war** and **dummy-eu.war**. This makes them accessible via the following URLs:

```
http://server/dummy/
http://server/dummy-eu/
```

We've recently made a change where we can eliminate the **dummy-eu.war** and just use **dummy.war**. However, we have several applications that are still configured to use **dummy-eu.war**. We would like to remove **dummy-eu.war**, but then point the URL for it to use **dummy.war**, so that:

```
http://server/dummy/
http://server/dummy-eu/ <- redirects to /dummy/
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this in Tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat doesn't provide this feature out of the box. You'll need to deploy a minimal web application to dummy-eu to do the redirect.